# blazor without web assembly

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

Disclaimer: I am new in blazor and .NET.

My question:
Is it possible to use blazor client/server without webassembly?

My understanding:

- Blazor client uses web assembly and download the whole .NET core, (dependencies+ CLR) in the browser.
- In the blazor server only frontend resources are loaded (HTML+CSS+JS) and the library persistent two-way is loaded to send to the server updates. So in this case **NO web assembly** is used.

Is it the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is the case. What is downloaded with a blazor server application is basically a javascript client which keeps a SignalR connection with the server which serves the content and changes in the application.

Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-5.0#blazor-server)